# My Module install script isn't running

Tags: module, install-script

I'm fairly sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't see it.

I've added an install script to a module I've built, I've double checked it against Alan Storm's excellent tutorial, and I'm sure everything is correct, but it won't play ball.

I'm clearing the entry from core_resource each time, and I'm clearing the cache (all of the cache is disabled anyway, but I'm clearing it for good measure!!)

config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
      <modules>
            <Lw_Restrict>
                  <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Lw_Restrict>
      </modules>
      <global>
            <resources>
                  <restrict_setup>
                        <setup>
                              <module>Lw_Restrict</module>
                              <class>Lw_Restrict_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                        </setup>
                        <connection>
                              <use>core_setup</use>
                        </connection>
                  </restrict_setup>
            </resources>
      </global>
</config>
```

./app/code/local/Lw/Restrict/Model/Resource/Mysql4/Setup.php

```
<?php

class Lw_Restrict_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {


}
```

./app/code/local/Lw/Restrict/sql/restrict_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php

```
<?php

die("Noop");
```

The install script was previously more complicated, adding attributes etc, but I stripped it back to this test just to make sure it wasn't that.

What happens when I clear everything and run this is that the site loads as normal, a row is added to core_resource, but it doesn't die (and previously it didn't add the attributes)

If someone can point out what I'm missing that'd be great!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you deleted the reference in the database to your module's version number?

It should be in the `core_resource` table under `restrict_setup`

If so, perhaps try `<lw_restrict_setup>` rather than `<restrict_setup>` and remove the `<connection>` tag altogether.

Also, rename the `restrict_setup` folder in

```
/app/code/local/Lw/Restrict/sql/restrict_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php
```

to

```
lw_restrict_setup
```

and then add within your `<global>` tag:

```
<models>
    <restrict_setup>
        <restrict>
            <class>Lw_Restrict_Model</class>
        </restrict>
    </restrict_setup>
</models>
```

Comment: Thanks - didn't need to add to <models>, but made your other suggested changes and it worked!